# PlatformException(invalid_image, Cannot load representation of type public.png, NSItemProviderErrorDomain, null)

Tags: ios, flutter, imagepicker

I am getting folowing error for image_picker flutter implementaion,The selected image cannot be retrieved

```
PlatformException(invalid_image, Cannot load representation of type public.png, NSItemProviderErrorDomain, null)
```

use  image_picker: ^1.0.4

this issue happening on my iphone

I expect to be able to get selected pictures